# Swift: Quick/Nimble running async test shows error: 'InvalidNimbleAPIUsage', reason: 'expect(...).toEventually(...) can only run on the main thread.'

Tags: xcode10, swift5, ios10.3, quick-nimble

I'm implementing a test case using Quick/Nimble making network request (URLRequest) but I'm getting this error:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidNimbleAPIUsage', reason: 'expect(...).toEventually(...) can only run on the main thread.'
```

This is my test case:

```
 expect(someVar).toEventually(equal("bar"), timeout: 0.2, pollInterval: 0.1, description: "time")
```

If change my implementation:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    expect(someVar).toEventually(equal("bar"), timeout: 0.2, pollInterval: 0.1, description: "time")
}
```

I get this error:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidNimbleAPIUsage', reason: 'Nested async expectations are not allowed to avoid creating flaky tests.

Any of you has an idea how can make this test case to work using `Quick/Nimble` ?

I'll really appreciate your help